# SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: синтаксис

Проблема: выдает "invalid syntax"
Программа ниже:

```
print('Контроль веса')

print('Введите ваш рост и вес')

h = input('Рост(см)->')

w = input('Вес(кг)->')

opt = h - w

if w == opt:

print('Ваш вес оптимален!')

elif w < opt:

rly = opt - w

print('Вам надо поправиться на', rly, 'кг.')

else w > opt:

rly = w - opt

print('Вам надо похудеть на', rly, 'кг.')
```

Comment: @ShAd0W, ну в метках хотя бы язык указали, на котором пишете.

Comment: @ShAd0W, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду, это питон, и проблема в том, что автор вопроса забыл, что в нем отступы важны.

```
print('Контроль веса')
print('Введите ваш рост и вес')
h = input('Рост(см)->')
w = input('Вес(кг)->')
opt = h - w
if w == opt:
  print('Ваш вес оптимален!')
elif w < opt:
  rly = opt - w
  print('Вам надо поправиться на', rly, 'кг.')
else:
  rly = w - opt
  print('Вам надо похудеть на', rly, 'кг.')
```

Также условие возле последнего else не нужно. Во-первых, это не по синтаксису, а во-вторых, последнее условие и так выполнится.